# Swagger apis not displaying for some classes

Tags: javascript, xml, spring, maven, swagger

I am using swagger to list apis for a project; however, some do not appear in the swagger-ui, even though I can access the xml file in the browser fine and I have used the @Api and @ApiOperation tags.

As you can see, the about-controller shows up fine. In the class it contains @RequestMapping's for the specified functions and @Api for the title.

I do the exact same for an attribute-controller api and I see the xml on localhost fine. However, the swagger-ui doesnt seem to pick it up.

Here are the specs I am working with from Maven pom.xml file: swagger-core(and annotations)_2.9.1, version 1.2.2. I really appreciate any help!

Comment: On google-chrome, hit F12 to open developer tools, then refresh your page to see what error (if any) is reported. It might be just a simple typo.

Comment: @FelipeAlmeida thanks for the response! I opened up the console and I've seen this do this before: It gives the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null". I am starting to think this is the problem now because it appears when I search all of api-docs or one that doesnt work, but not when I look up an api that does display with the swagger ui. Do you know what this issue is? Thanks again!